# Ошибка в Java Script - Список Объектов

Tags: javascript, объекты, список

Суть задания - Имеем список объектов :

```
const o = {
    'Bob': 'Mary',
    'Kate': 'Mary',
    'Jack': 'Jim',
    'Ann': 'Jim'
};
```

Ожидаемый результат : {'Mary': ['Bob', 'Kate'], 'Jim': ['Jack', 'Ann']}

Добавил функцию, пустой result который мы будем заполнять, но при выводе на косноль я получаю пустоту.

Мой код :

```
const o = {
    'Bob': 'Mary',
    'Kate': 'Mary',
    'Jack': 'Jim',
    'Ann': 'Jim'
};

function getParents(children) {
   const result = {};
   for (let name of children) {
    if (!result[o[name]]) result[o[name]] = [name];
    else result[o[name]].push(name);
  }
  console.log(result);
};
```

Буду рад, если поможете найти решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
    'Bob': 'Mary',
    'Kate': 'Mary',
    'Jack': 'Jim',
    'Ann': 'Jim'
};

function getParents(children) {
   const result = {};
   for (let name in children) {
    if (!result[children[name]]) result[children[name]] = [name];
    else result[children[name]].push(name);
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(getParents(obj));
```